# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages (Composer update)

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

I have this issue when i tried to install this package

```
"codesleeve/laravel-stapler": "1.0.*"
```

This is my composer.json file

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "laravel/socialite": "^2.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*",
    "greggilbert/recaptcha": "^2.1",        
    "bican/roles": "2.1.*",
    "kodeine/laravel-acl": "~1.0@dev",
    "nesbot/carbon": "^1.21",
    "dansmith/laravel5-foundation": "0.3.*",
    "codesleeve/laravel-stapler": "1.0.*"
},
```

This is the error:

```
C:\laragon\www\wasamar   Fri 07/08/2016  5:02:36.56
```

composer update

> in Unknown on line 0
>
> Loading composer repositories with package information
>
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.

Problem 1

```
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.2.39                                                                                         
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.39                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.38                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.37                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.36                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.35                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.34                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.33                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.32                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.31                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.30                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.29                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.28                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.27                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.26                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.25                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.24                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.23                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.22                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.21                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.20                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.19                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.18                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.17                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.16                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.15                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.14                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.13                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.12                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.11                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.10                                                                                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.9                                                                                   
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.8                                                                                   
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.7                                                                                   
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.6                                                                                   
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.5                                                                                   
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.4                                                                                   
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.3                                                                                   
    - Installation request for dansmith/laravel5-foundation 0.3.* -> satisfiable by dansmith/laravel5-foundation[v0.3.0].                  
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.2                                                                                   
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.1                                                                                   
    - dansmith/laravel5-foundation v0.3.0 requires illuminate/pagination 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/pagination[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.
.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].                                                        
    - don't install illuminate/pagination v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0                                                    
    - don't install illuminate/pagination v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0                                                   
    - don't install illuminate/pagination v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0                                                   
    - don't install illuminate/pagination v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0                                                    
    - don't install illuminate/pagination v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0                                                   
    - don't install illuminate/pagination v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0                                                   
    - don't install illuminate/pagination v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0                                                   
    - don't install illuminate/pagination v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0                                                   
    - don't install illuminate/pagination v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0                                                   
    - don't install illuminate/pagination v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0                                                   
    - don't install illuminate/pagination v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0                                                    
    - don't install illuminate/pagination v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0                                                    
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.2.0, v5.2.1, v5.2.10, v5.2.11, v5.2.12, v5.2.
3, v5.2.14, v5.2.15, v5.2.16, v5.2.17, v5.2.18, v5.2.19, v5.2.2, v5.2.20, v5.2.21, v5.2.22, v5.2.23, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5
2.28, v5.2.29, v5.2.3, v5.2.30, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.33, v5.2.34, v5.2.35, v5.2.36, v5.2.37, v5.2.38, v5.2.39, v5.2.4, v5.2.5, v5.2.6, v5
2.7, v5.2.8, v5.2.9].                                                                                                                                  
C:\laragon\www\wasamar   Fri 07/08/2016  5:09:59.40                                                                                        
λ Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

Comment: try this `composer global update`

Comment: Thanks @Edvin Tenovim for the edit, i really want to edit it.

Comment: No problems. :) Edited for better appearance and better understanding your question.

Answer (score 0):

Open `config/app.php`

and in the providers array insert the code below:

`'Codesleeve\LaravelStapler\Providers\L5ServiceProvider'`

Answer (score 0):

I Had this problem too..  But I fixed it using `composer global update`